# Bit level soft decisions of m-ary symbols for LDPC decoding for DVB-S2 standard

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, log-likelihood

I'd need to know how to estimate the log-likelihood ratio of a m-ary symbol to apply message passing decoding on it on AWGN channel.

For the BPSK case, we know that it is $L(u_n)=2y_n/σ^2$. But how shall we proceed when we have other modulation orders, such as QPSK, 8-PSK, 16-APSK and 32-APSK (The ones appearing in DVB-S2 standard)?

I came across [one formula](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24697/how-to-compute-bit-level-soft-decisions-from-an-m-ary-symbol/42360#42360) appearing as an answer to this question but as stated there only serves for QAM. Also it has been negatively voted and has no reference whatsoever so cannot be sure about it.

Could anyone lend me a hand with this?

Many thanks in advance, and BR.

Comment: If implementation allows, it might be easiest to just numerically integrate over your decision region at every SNR. Otherwise, a common rough upper bound (found in Wireless Comms by Goldsmith if you need a ref) is to assume any wrong codeword happens uniformly with total probability of error = P(noise > min distance between constellation points) which for AWGN is just a Q function. But if you've set up your constellation carefully so that adjacent points are assigned similar bits, this approximation won't capture any of that.

Comment: Check [this reference](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2001/HPL-2001-246.pdf) on the computation of LLRs for QAM modulation. It also provides approximate closed-form expression for the LLRs that in practise perform very well. You should be able to extend the approach also to non-QAM constellations.

Comment: The answer depends on the bit labels of the various points in your signal constellation. To each bit encoded in this symbol (2 of them for QPSK, 3 for 8-PSK, 4 in 16-QAM etc) you partition the signal constellation into two parts according to the value of the bit of interest. Then you sum the probabilities of the individual signal points in the two constellations. Take the log of the ratio of the two sums.

Comment: In other words the (previously) downvoted answer in the linked question at DSP.SE gives IMHO the correct formula (assuming known SNR and AWGN). What I described above holds in the absence of a priori information on the relative likelihoods of this symbol. When you get into iterated demodulation, then it becomes more complicated.

Comment: One further note. When I implemented this I ran into some numerical issues. IIRC I solved them by initializing the two sums to some small positive epsilon instead of zero (basically to cut off the LLRs below a certain bound), but I don't remember the exact details. May have been due to limitations of my data types? May be the issue only showed up when doing multiantenna transmission/reception, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me out. I was wondering if an specific way of performing these decisions for all modulation orders (QPSK, 8-PSK, 16-APSK and 32-APSK) did exist in the standard. I didn't find this information anywhere. Best regards, and may you have a nice week!